# hiding a php file/folder with php file from ftp user

Tags: permissions, ftp

Is it possible to hide the php files or hide a folder with php files from FTP user accessing? But the files can be executed on a webserver?

Comment: Yes. If you need detailed instructions to achieve it, you have to specify at least the FTP server's name and version.

Comment: ProFTPd version 1.33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may hide those files using the [HideFiles directive](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_HideFiles.html). Then you must treat those files as if they don't exist, using the [IgnoreHidden directive](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_IgnoreHidden.html).